# Python - Read and plot only the latest files

Tags: python, csv, datestamp

I have multiple csv files (each file generated per day) with generic filename (say `file_`) and I append date-stamps to them.

For example: `file_2015_10_19`, `file_2015_10_18`and so on.

Now, I only want to read the 5 latest files and create a comparison plot.

For me plotting is no issue but sorting all the files and reading only the latest 5 is.

Comment: Once you have a list of file names, why not just do a regular old sort on the list? e.g., `last_five = sorted(list_of_files)[-5:]`. This is assuming that each file prefix this is the same.

Comment: Thanks clwainwright! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read all the files, and then sort them. There isn't a shortcut I'm afraid.

You can sort them by the last modified time, or parse the date component and sort by the date

```
import glob
import os
import datetime

file_mask = 'file_*'
ts = 'file_%Y_%m_%d'
path_to_files = r'/foo/bar/zoo/'

def get_date_from_file(s):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, ts)

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_files, file_mask))
sorted_files = sorted(all_files, key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))[-5:]
sorted_by_date = sorted(all_files, key=get_date_from_file)[-5:]
```

Comment: I think you mean `[-5:]`, not `[:-5]`. The former gives the last five items in the list, the latter gives everything except the last five.

Comment: Thanks Burhan! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# list all files in the directory - returns a list of files
files = os.listdir('.')

# sort the list in reverse order
files.sort(reverse=True)

# the top 5 items in the list are the files you need
sorted_files = files[:-5]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @mac-pan mentions that he appends the date stamps to the file, so the above should work. Besides, I tried the same code on my local (more than once) before posting and noticed `files[:-5]` works.

Comment: Thanks Adi! I'll try this method as well. Best!